# Toggling a Dialogflow Chat Window by clicking on a Material-UI Floating Action Button in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, dialogflow-es, api-ai

In the below code snippet, I am trying to toggle `<ChatWidget />`, which is a Dialogflow Chat Window, when a user clicks on the `<FloatingActionButton/>` with the default state set to `false`. 
When clicked on the Material-UI Floating Action Button, it does not toggle the state to `true`.
I am using Material UI v1.0.0-beta34.
Here is the code snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChatWidget from './ChatWidget';
import FloatingActionButton from './Fab';
class ChatComponent extends Component {
constructor( props ){
  super( props )
  this.state = { show : false };
  this.toggleDiv = this.toggleDiv.bind(this)
 }
toggleDiv = () => {
  const { show } = this.state;
  this.setState( { show : !show } )
}
render() {
  return (
  <div>
    <div>
      { this.state.show && <ChatWidget /> }
    </div>
  <FloatingActionButton onClick={ this.toggleDiv } />
  </div>
   );
  }
 }
 export default ChatComponent;
```

The page without clicking the FAB looks like this:

[image: default state]

The desired functionality when the FAB is clicked is shown below:

[image: desired functionality on click of FAB when state is toggled to true]

Any help or suggestions regarding the proper way to toggle the `<ChatWidget />` on clicking the `<FloatingActionButton />` is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was `<FloatingActionButton />` is a custom component that I made. If I have to make the FloatingActionButton respond to clicks, I have to add the OnClick property in the Material UI `<Button/>` component itself.
The modified code that works:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChatWidget from './ChatWidget';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
const style = {
 margin: 0,
 top: 'auto',
 right: 20,
 bottom: 20,
 left: 'auto',
 position: 'fixed',
 backgroundColor:'#E65100',
 color:'#FFFFFF',
};

  class ChatComponent extends Component {
   constructor( props ){
    super( props )
    this.state = { show : false };

    this.toggleDiv = this.toggleDiv.bind(this)
   }

   toggleDiv = () => {
    const { show } = this.state;
    this.setState( { show : !show } )
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <div>
       { this.state.show && <ChatWidget /> }
      </div>
     <Button variant="fab" aria-label="add" style={style} onClick={ 
      this.toggleDiv } >
    <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
     </Button>
     </div>
     );
   }
  }
  export default ChatComponent;
```